# Gridview cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my web forms page, I have this huge GridView.  I make it refresh every five minutes since the data has to be up to date.

It has sort options, so upon every refresh, I use cookies through every refresh to remember the search and sort options.

In the `Page_Load` function, this is how I do it.

```
HttpCookie cookieStat = new HttpCookie("cookieStat");
cookieStat = Request.Cookies["cookieStat"];
ViewState["thisWebPageViewStatus"] = 
    (cookieStat == null || cookieStat.Value == DEFAULTSTATUS) ?
    DEFAULTSTATUS : cookieStat.Value;
```

Before I knew it, I ended up having a bunch of cookies like this.  How would I make this more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new `HttpCookie` by calling

```
HttpCookie cookieStat = new HttpCookie("cookieStat");
```

which is overwritten in the next line

```
cookieStat = Request.Cookies["cookieStat"];
```

is superflous. This can be simplyfied like

```
HttpCookie cookieStat = Request.Cookies["cookieStat"];
```

---

This tenary

> ```
> ViewState["thisWebPageViewStatus"] = 
>     (cookieStat == null || cookieStat.Value == DEFAULTSTATUS) ?
>            DEFAULTSTATUS : cookieStat.Value;
> ```

is a little bit strange. Why would you want to check for `DEFAULTSTATUS` and if it is true assign it ?

A much better version would be

```
ViewState["thisWebPageViewStatus"] = (cookieStat == null) ? DEFAULTSTATUS : cookieStat.Value;
```

and you should also consider to use constants for the strings too.

---

The variable name `cookieStat` could also use a facelifting to something more meaningful like e.g `searchAndSortOptionsCookie`